# How do I search the GDELT database hosted in Google's BigQuery for a keyword, as I can with the GDELT API?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, gdelt

How can I query articles in BigQuery GDELT that make mention of a keyword such as "climate change" (despite the lack of a keyword column)? Admittedly, I am a complete novice at working with databases and may be misunderstanding something simple, so please feel free to point anything out.

I am attempting to query articles pertaining to keywords of interest in order to trace the provenance of a query claim. I would use the GDELT API, which supports fast querying with keywords, but it only returns articles in the past 3 months. The nature of the problem I'm interested in likely requires locating information potentially years ago. Thus I figured I could try querying the public GDELT Events database in Google BigQuery, however I am confused how to query by keyword, as there is no column/feature for keywords or event content.

Answer (score 0):

Did you meant Gdelt public dataset stored in bigquery ? You can view the dataset [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/the-gdelt-project/gdelt-2-events?filter=solution-type:dataset&id=a41570ce-2ee5-444c-80d8-1dd6ee6602ad&walkthrough_tutorial_id=java_gae_quickstart). You can simply run select query against this dataset or even tune the query to apply condition to your use case.
I would suggest visiting this article for more details about querying and BQ's capabilities when writing querys and I believe a good starting point for writing queries in BQ: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/introduction-sql